# Cannot get facebook page id from url if it contains dash

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.x

I have facebook url like `https://www.facebook.com/youtube-7270241753/`

I need to get id of that page.

I am using Facebook SDK for C#.
I have FacebookClient with access token.

```
dynamic response = await FbClient.GetTaskAsync($"{input.Url.Replace("www", "graph")}?fields=id");
```

After this request I get next error :

> (OAuthException - #803) (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: youtube-7270241753

I think problem is in dash. When I post url just like `https://www.facebook.com/youtube` everything works fine.

How can I proceed with dash in url? Should I manually parse id from that type of url?

---

I resolve this issue maybe not in best way, but...

As I can see there are 3 different url types for fb page:

- /pages/{pageName}/{pageId}
- /{pageName}-{pageId}
- /{pageName}

For first case I just take latest token.
For 2nd case - split token by dash and get latest part.
And for 3rd - I am using FbClient and from response get page Id.

Comment: Those URLs are usually a combination of page title and page id, you get them for pages that do not explicitly have a username set I think. You will need to split this, so that you get the numeric ID separately. Then you can use that in your request.

Comment: @CBroe, so I can just split it and get page id... and additional request to facebook isn't needed. Ok. Thanks